# Cypress sends request twice to the backend

Tags: cypress

I have the following test

```
let rxId = "";
let basketAuthToken = "";
let basketId = "";
let replacedBody = "";
cy.fixture(`payload/${ordersPostPayload}`).then((Body) => {
  cy.readFile(`temp/resultIdFile.json`).then((resultIdFile) => {
    Id = resultIdFile.lastSucceededRxId;
    basketAuthToken = resultIdFile.baskets[0].authToken;
    basketId = resultIdFile.baskets[0].basketId;
    cy.log(`the value of the read value is ${Id}`);
    replacedBody = JSON.stringify(Body).split(`$Id`).join(Id);
    cy.writeFile(`temp/ordersPostPayload.json`, replacedBody);

    cy.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: `https://***/ops/orders`,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Channel: "**",
        "EsbApi-Subscription-Key": `****`,
        "Accept-Language": `en-US`,
        "basket-token": basketAuthToken,
        "basket-id": basketId,
        redirectUrl: "****/evaluate-payment",
        cancelUrl: "****/evaluate-payment",
      },
      body: replacedBody,
      failOnStatusCode: false,
    }).then((response) => {
      cy.writeFile("temp/result.json", response);
    });
  });
});
```

The request is sent to the backend. On cypress GUI the request is just fired once. but when I check the backend I can see two requests.

Comment: This code does not suggest it gets executed twice. Isn't it something outside of what we can see, e.g. working in your IDE with open Cypress Test Runner and saving your .js file likely means Cypress will execute your test case again. Also, what exactly and where are you checking on the backend? Can you find timestamps for those two requests, how far apart from each other are they?

Comment: They are 7 seconds apart. I work only with the runner closed.